# Use Enum value for a value in a dropdownlist ASPCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums

Im trying to use a value from an enum I've declared in my code previously

Here is the enum :

```
public enum CompanyStatus
{
    WaitingForApproval = 1,
    Approved = 2,
    Disapproved = 3
}
```

Here is the select list where I am trying to use that Id that has been already declared

```
<select id="CompanyStatusFilter" validateme="true" class="form-control fullWidth" placeholder="Status" data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="min1">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="(int)Core.Engine.CompanyStatus.Approved">Approved</option>
                            <option value="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<CompanyStatus>">Waiting for approval</option>                                
                        </select>
```

I don't want to explicitly type in the id as the value.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it would be better if you used the helper for Enums for example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Html.GetEnumSelectList(Model.GetType()))
```

and on the Enum values you can use the `[Display(Name = "Test 1")]` attribute to control what gets shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetEnumSelectList` to render a select for the enum values.

```
<select name="CompanyStatus" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof (CompanyStatus))">
</select>
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.getenumselectlist?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to to get the id of the enum by Converting it to an Int32

```
<option value="@Convert.ToInt32(Core.Engine.CompanyStatus.WaitingForApproval)">Waiting for approval</option>
```